# How to derive the $\log$ of fraction of two Gaussian distribution

Tags: image-processing, gaussian

I am designing a function $A(x)$ that map $x\to \{0,1\}$. The function $A$ can be expressed as
$$A(x)=\begin{cases}
1 \text{  if $p_1(x) \ge p_2(x)$}\\ 
0 \text{  otherwises}
\end{cases}
$$
where $p_1$ and $p_2$ are Gaussian distribution:

$p_1(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_1}\exp\left( {-\frac{(x-\mu_1)^2}{2\sigma_1^2}} \right)$;

$p_2(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_2}\exp\left( {-\frac{(x-\mu_2)^2}{2\sigma_2^2}} \right)$.

Could you help me to derive a short form of $A(x)$ ?

This is my solution. However, it maybe wrong

I derived the bellow eq.
$$A(x)=\begin{cases}
1 \text{  if $\log \frac{p_1(x)}{p_2(x)}>0$}\\ 
0 \text{  otherwises}
\end{cases}
$$
where $\log(e)=1$

We have
$$\log \frac{p_1(x)}{p_2(x)}=\log \frac{\sigma_2}{\sigma_1}+\left( {\frac{x-\mu_2}{\sqrt{2}\sigma_2}} \right)^2-\left( {\frac{x-\mu_1}{\sqrt{2}\sigma_1}} \right)^2$$

Hence, my final solution is
$$A(x)=\begin{cases}
1 \text{  if $\left (\log \frac{\sigma_2}{\sigma_1}+\left( {\frac{x-\mu_2}{\sqrt{2}\sigma_2}} \right)^2-\left( {\frac{x-\mu_1}{\sqrt{2}\sigma_1}} \right)^2 \right) \ge 0$}\\ 
0 \text{  otherwises}
\end{cases}
$$

Thanks in advance

Comment: You somehow lost the square in your "final solution".

Comment: because $\log(\exp(-x^2))=-2x$,right?

Comment: No, $\log(\exp(-x^2))=-x^2$.

Comment: The $\sqrt{2}$ in the denominators of your final formula should be a $2$. Then it's correct, but you should work it out to become a condition on $x$. As it stands, it can't really be evaluated that easily.

Comment: Because I put square out side, thus, inside the denominators only remains $\sqrt{2}$, is it correct? What does it means of "out to become a condition on $x$", In my case, $x,\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\mu_1,\mu_2$ are given

Comment: Oh yes, I missed the squares outside, so it's indeed correct. What I meant is that right now you don't really see for which values of $x$ your inequality is satisfied, so you have to reformulate it as an explicit condition on $x$, like $A\le x \le B$ with constants $A$ and $B$ that obviously depend on $\mu_i$ and $\sigma_i$.

Comment: Could you help me solve it? I have no expert in that inequality. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your final condition is correct, but it doesn't show explicitly for which values of $x$ it is satisfied. This can be worked out as follows. From what you have it follows that $p_1(x)\ge p_2(x)$ is equivalent to

$$0\ge x^2(\sigma_2^2-\sigma_1^2)-2x(\mu_1\sigma_2^2-\mu_2\sigma_1^2)+\mu_1^2\sigma_2^2-\mu_2^2\sigma_1^2-2\sigma_1^2\sigma_2^2\log\left(\frac{\sigma_2}{\sigma_1}\right)\tag{1}$$

Let's first consider the case $\sigma_1=\sigma_2$. From $(1)$ it follows that in this case the condition on $x$ becomes

$$x\ge \frac{\mu_1^2-\mu_2^2}{2(\mu_1-\mu_2)}
= \frac{\mu_1+\mu_2}{2}\tag{2}$$

where we assume $\mu_1\neq\mu_2$ because otherwise $p_1(x)=p_2(x)$, which makes no sense.

In the case $\sigma_1\neq\sigma_2$, we have to consider $(1)$ as a quadratic inequality in $x$, which is satisfied with equality for the following values of $x$:

$$\begin{align}x_1&=\frac{a}{2}-\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{4}-b}\\
x_2&=\frac{a}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{4}-b}\end{align}\tag{3}$$

with

$$\begin{align}a&=\frac{2(\mu_1\sigma_2^2-\mu_2\sigma_1^2)}{\sigma_2^2-\sigma_1^2}\\
b&=\frac{\mu_1^2\sigma_2^2-\mu_2^2\sigma_1^2-2\sigma_1^2\sigma_2^2\log\left(\frac{\sigma_2}{\sigma_1}\right)}{\sigma_2^2-\sigma_1^2}\end{align}\tag{4}$$

Depending on the sign of $\sigma_2-\sigma_1$ we have two conditions equivalent to $p_1(x)\ge p_2(x)$:

$$\begin{align}\sigma_2>\sigma_1:\quad & x_1\le x\le x_2\\
\sigma_2<\sigma_1:\quad & x\le x_1\text{ or }x\ge x_2\end{align}\tag{5}$$

The inequalities in $(5)$ state explicit conditions on the variable $x$ that can be easily evaluated.

**EDIT:** As suggested by Dilip Sarwate in a comment it can be instructive to distinguish another special case: $\sigma_1\neq\sigma_2$ and $\mu_1=\mu_2=\mu$. In that case the limits $x_1$ and $x_2$ of the decision regions given by $(3)$ lie symmetrical to the common mean $\mu$, and $(3)$ simplifies to

$$x_{1,2}=\mu\pm\sqrt{\frac{2\sigma_1^2\sigma_2^2\log\left(\frac{\sigma_2}{\sigma_1}\right)}{\sigma_2^2-\sigma_1^2}}$$

Of course, the conditions $(5)$ remain valid.

Comment: +1 I improved (2) a little; I hope you approve.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: Very good, silly me ...

Comment: Nice, guys!!!!!

Comment: Actually, if I may suggest: there are two special cases where the answers are simpler, and perhaps both should be considered separately before looking at the more general answer. (1) $\sigma_1=\sigma_2, \mu_1 \neq \mu_2$ where the threshold is $\frac{\mu_1+\mu_2}{2}$; drawing a sketch of the two pdfs reveals, without any algebra why the threshold must lie halfway between the means, and (2) $\sigma_1 \neq \sigma_2, \mu_1 = \mu_2$ in which case the decision is to choose one hypothesis if $x$ is far away from the common mean, and the other hypothesis if $x$ is near the common mean; again sketch!

Comment: @DilipSarwate: I've added that second special case to my answer.